# Call only parent method

Tags: php, inheritance, codeigniter-3

Lets imagine example - we have three classes

```
class A {

  protected function render()
  {
     echo 'class A';
  }

  protected show_error()
  {
     $this->render();
     exit('error');
  }  

}

class B extends A {
   protected function render()
   {
     echo 'class B';
     parent::render();
   } 

}


class C extends B {
{
}
```

So I create some code

```
c = new C();
c->show_error();
```

Output will be

```
class B
class A
error
```

Question is - why "show_error" method call "render" method from class B ?
Why just dont call only "render" from class A itself?

Could somebody explain this? And is it possible to do that in "my way"?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah u are right, cause using $this-> makes this behavior, so using "self" do the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic OOP

```
class A {

  protected function render()
  {
     echo 'class A';
  }

  public function show_error()
  {
     self::render(); // this is what you're after
     exit('error');
  }  

}
```

The reason it's calling `B::render()` is because `C` extends `B` and `B` reimplements `render()`

Also, show_error() should be public. otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: I am working in develop mode and all error messages on but there is no errors :)